# Why Syrian Idolatresses okay but Canaanite not?

Tags: history

Why was Abraham, and later Isaac and Rebecca, dead set against their sons, Isaac, Jacob and Esau, respectively, marrying idolatrous Canaanite and Hittite women, but perfectly okay with them marrying women from amongst their own equally idolatrous close relatives?  Wouldn't it have been better to have each marry a woman from within the camp?

Is it a Royalty/Aristocracy thing?

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109760

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did Avraham ask Eliezer to go to his family?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109760/why-did-avraham-ask-eliezer-to-go-to-his-family)